Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Show that if $x^2y=2x+y$ , then if $y\ne 0$ then $x\ne 0$
My solution: Suppose $x^2y=2x+y$, $y≠0$ and $x=0$. Substituting $x=0$ into the equation will follow through that $y=0$, which contradicts that $y\ne 0$. Hence if $x^2y=2x+y \implies y \ne 0 \implies x \ne 0$.
The correct solution provided to me used the contra-positive method. I am wondering my application of the contradiction method used here is correct? Thanks!

The if-statement is only false , if $y \ne 0$ and $x=0$ which you ruled out.

The overall logic of your proof is correct, but it would be better to be provide more detail. For instance, actually substitute $x=0$ and show how this leads to $y=0$.

Substituting $x=0$ gives "$0=y$" at once , this need not be worked out further.

Both proofs say that "$x=0 \implies y=0$ and therefore $y\not=0 \implies x \not =0$".

You can use \implies for the $\implies$ symbol.

You wrote "$x^2y=2x+y \implies y \ne 0 \implies x \ne 0$" but I think what you meant, and what your proof by contradiction correctly (absolutely correct) showed was "$x^2y=2x+y & y\ne 0 \implies x\ne 0$".  $x^2y=2x+y$ does not imply $y\ne 0$, of course because we can always have $x^2\cdot 0 = 2x + 0$ as a possibility.

Might help to include the "correct solution"  I had to surmise what the intended contrapositive proof was.

Your proof by contradiction is absolutely correct.  Proofs by contradictions can often be very similar to proofs by contrapositive.  The difference unsually is that in a proof by contraposite you prove the negation of the conclusion yields a negation of the hypothesis, whereas a proof by contradiction is showing the negation of the conclusion and the hypothesis are mutually exclusive.
Here we have $x^2y= 2x + y$ as a given. And we hare asked to prove the Hypothesis $y\ne 0$ implies the conclusion $x\ne 0$.
The proof by contradiction assumes the negation of the conclusion, $x=0$, and the $y\ne 0$ and notes that $0^2\cdot y = 0$ and $2\cdot 0+y =y$ and $y\ne 0$ and so, we have $0 = y$ as well as $y\ne 0$.  So Hypothesis: $x\ne 0$ and Negation of conclusion: $x=0$ are incompatable.  So if Hypothesis: $x\ne 0$ then Conclusion: $x=0$.
The proof be contrapositive assumes the negation of the conclusion, $x=0$ but not the hypothesis, $y\ne 0$ but instead proves the negation of the hypothesis, $y=0$.  It does so in the exact same way as proof by contradiction.  $0^2\cdot y= 0$ and $2\cdot 0 + y = y$ so $y = 0$.  Thus Negation of conclusion implies negation of hypothesis.  So hypothesis implies conclusion.
I suppose I should point out that in you proof by contradiction you never actually directly used the hypothesis, $y\ne 0$, to reach your contradiction; you just held on to it until the very end and when you concluded $y=0$, you brought it out.  It could be argued that, in spirit, your proof is actually a contrapositive proof.
To do a proof by contradiction might by that actively and directly use $y\ne 0$ might go something like:
$x^2y = 2x + y$ so $x^2y - y=2x$ so $(x^2-1)y = 2x$ and as $y\ne 0$ we may divide both sides by $y$ to get. $x^2-1 =x\cdot \frac 2y$. As we are assuming  $x=0$, we have LHS is $-1$ but the RHS is $0$ so we reach the contradiction $-1 = 0$.
....
BTW.  Your post has a misstatement.  You wrote "$x^2y=2x+y \implies y \ne 0 \implies x \ne 0$".  When I think you meant was "$(x^2y=2x+y $ and $y \ne 0) \implies x \ne 0$

It's easier to show the equivalent negation ($A\Longrightarrow B$ is the sane as $B^c\Longrightarrow A^c$): of $x=0$ then $y=0$ which is trivial in this case...

I would argue the op demonstrates an easier proof. Your method leads to a proof by cases

Again , I disagree : There is only one case , namely $x=0$. So, this is no "proof by cases".

Agreed that the original poster's approach is elegant.
An inferior alternative approach is to consider the equation as a 2nd degree equation in $~x,~$ and solve for $~x~$ as a function of $~y.$
From one of the premises of the problem, you are given that $~y \neq 0.~$ Then:
$$x^2(y) +x(-2) + (-y) = 0 \implies $$
$$x = \frac{1}{2y} \left[ ~2 \pm \sqrt{ ~4 + 4y^2 ~} ~\right]. \tag1 $$
For $~x~$ to equal $~0,~$ you need $~\displaystyle \sqrt{ ~4 + 4y^2 ~}~$ to equal $~2.~$
This implies that $~\displaystyle [ ~4 + 4y^2 ~]~$ equals $~4.~$
This can't happen, because of the premise that $~y \neq 0.~$

Why do you say "without loss of generality, assume $y\ne 0$".  That is a HUGE loss of generality, and that's not the point.  We have $x^2y -2x -y=0$ and if $y=0$ then $-2x=0$ which is fine.  But the thing we actually want to prove is IF $y\ne 0$.... so we can assume $y=0$, not wolog, but as hypotheses.  So just say "$x^2y -2x -y =0$.  And if $y\ne 0$ then....."

@fleablood Your comment threw me for a moment, and then I read your comment more carefully.  I agree that my use of the phrase "without loss of generality" is not appropriate, and instead, I should have simply referred to the assertion that $~y \neq 0,~$ as one of the premises.  I have edited my answer accordingly.
